# What is meant by "build step" for setuptools and source distributions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I want to understand Python packages, downloaded using `pip`, on a deeper level.

Often they are just described as something you generate using `setuptools`'s `setup.py` script.

From Python glossary, source distributions and wheel distributions are two distribution formats that largely differ wrt. a "**build step**".

What is meant by a build step?

In particular, I assume that a build step doesn't refer to generating .pyc files from the .py files, since Wheel explicitly mentions that the format doesn't include that (and it doesn't need a build step):

> This format does not imply that Python files have to be precompiled
> (Wheel intentionally does not include compiled Python files).

References:

https://packaging.python.org/guides/distributing-packages-using-setuptools/

> A “source distribution” is unbuilt (i.e. it’s not a Built
> Distribution), and requires a **build step** when installed by pip. Even
> if the distribution is pure Python (i.e. contains no extensions), it
> still involves a build step to build out the installation metadata
> from setup.py.

and

> A wheel is a built package that can be installed without needing to go
> through the “build” process.

Comment: This might help you understanding it: https://realpython.com/python-wheels/#what-is-a-python-wheel. I like to think of "installing a python package" as copying certain files to the correct locations on a system and "building" as pulling all files and packages and putting them into the wheel (basically a tar.gz container), so you don't have to afterwards. That is why you can install wheels without internet connection. Note that this is a very simplified version of what is happening :)

Comment: @DocDriven - I sometimes attempt to install wheels (at least I think so) that fail, since e.g. certain Linux packages are not installed on the target system (e.g. development headers). Isn't that contradictory to: *"building" as pulling all files and packages and putting them into the wheel (basically a tar.gz container)*?

Comment: I am not sure about that. I have found the PEPs specifying installation (https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0376/) and wheels (https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0427/) in general, maybe they contain useful information for you. I will have a read tonight and might re-evaluate my statement. Sorry if this caused confusion.